# Drop rows entries if a column values are all equal in grouped subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this example df:

```
info = {'name': ['Jason', 'Jason', 'Jason', 'Jason','Molly', 'Molly', 'Molly', 'Molly','Nicky', 'Nicky', 'Nicky', 'Nicky'], 
'city': ['Las Vegas', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Los Angeles','Las Vegas', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Los Angeles','Las Vegas', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Los Angeles'],
'Visits' :[2,2,2,2,1,3,4,1,2,8,2,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=info)
df
```

gives:

```
    name    city        Visits
0   Jason   Las Vegas     2
1   Jason   New York      2
2   Jason   Dallas        2
3   Jason   Los Angeles   2
4   Molly   Las Vegas     1
5   Molly   New York      3
6   Molly   Dallas        4
7   Molly   Los Angeles   1
8   Nicky   Las Vegas     2
9   Nicky   New York      8
10  Nicky   Dallas        2
11  Nicky   Los Angeles   8
```

I want to drop entries from `names` if all values under `Visits` are equivalent which is true in case of the `df['name']== jason`. I used drop_duplicates of two subsets `name and Visits` but the output drops also other duplicated values under other names.

```
df.drop_duplicates(['name','Visits'], keep=False)
```

This gives:

```
    name    city     Visits
5   Molly   New York    3
6   Molly   Dallas      4
```

output should be:

```
4   Molly   Las Vegas     1
5   Molly   New York      3
6   Molly   Dallas        4
7   Molly   Los Angeles   1
8   Nicky   Las Vegas     2
9   Nicky   New York      8
10  Nicky   Dallas        2
11  Nicky   Los Angeles   8
```

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df = df[df.groupby('name')['Visits'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
```

Or

```
df = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x['Visits'].nunique() != 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     name         city  Visits
4   Molly    Las Vegas       1
5   Molly     New York       3
6   Molly       Dallas       4
7   Molly  Los Angeles       1
8   Nicky    Las Vegas       2
9   Nicky     New York       8
10  Nicky       Dallas       2
11  Nicky  Los Angeles       8
```